# Select categories with subcategories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table that contains categories and subcategories, which looks like that:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create hierarchical tree of categories into `CategoryItem`:

```
public class CategoryItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CategoryItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I tried to group it into nice tree:

```
var result = await (from c in _context.Categories
                    where c.ParentId == null
                    select new CategoryItem
                    {
                        Name = c.Name,
                        Children = (from c2 in _context.Categories
                                    where c2.ParentId == c.CategoryId
                                    select new CategoryItem
                                    {
                                        Name = c2.Name
                                    }).ToList()
                    }).ToListAsync();
```

I get error:

> The type 'WebShop.Models.CategoryItem' appears in two structurally
>   incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A
>   type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if
>   the same properties are set in both places and those properties are
>   set in the same order.

I suspect that I have to assign something to the second object's `Children`, but I tried assigning `new List<CategoryItem>()` and `null`, but no results.

Comment: Bad tagging. The question has nothing to do with ASP.NET or MVC. It is about an ORM, probably Entity Framework but you didn't tell us the name or version.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yup, sorry about that.

Comment: What do you mean by *but I tried assigning new List<CategoryItem>() and null, but no results.*

Comment: @GiladGreen If I understand the error correctly, it requires that both initializations of `CategoryItem` need to have the same properties assigned. If this is the case then the second `new CategoryItem` also needs to have `Children`, but my subcategories' children are empty so I just tried to assign `new List<CategoryItem>() ` to them. I don't expect my subcategories to have children, but I guess `linq` requires me to supply value to `Children`.

Comment: @FCin - that is good :) I am just asking what is "but no results" mean? Still same exception? query executes but empty list at the end...

Comment: @GiladGreen I get the same exception.